# How to load a permission set from configuration

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, code-access-security

I'd like to know if there's some way to load a permission set from a configuration file.

For example, a permission set having these permissions:

- A FileIOPermission.
- A SqlClientPermission.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, there are actually multiple ways to do so.  With what particular aspect of the task do you need assistance?  (The "this is loading" bit doesn't make much sense to me.)

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu I didn't find how to load a permission set. I know there's a method `PermissionSet.ToXml()` but I don't know how to re-load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `PermissionSet.FromXml(SecurityElement.FromString(yourXmlRepresentation))` do the trick for your scenario?  If not, please post a sample of your config file contents, along with the code you are attempting to use to read the permission set.

Comment: It seems to be the right approach. I knew about `FromXml` method but I didn't know how to conver an XML string to that `SecurityElement`. I'm going to try it.

Comment: It's the solution. Thank you for your support!